# How to solve this problem in infinityfree file manager?

Tags: wordpress, customizer

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /home/vol8_5/epizy.com/epiz_34347250/htdocs/wp-content/themes/sydney/inc/customizer/controls/typography/class_sydney_typography.php on line 140
There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

I have been getting this problem after editing my files in the

I have been trying to solve this warning and now the customizer won't open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)